# Printing every Nth (8th character) from a file [Python]

Tags: python, function, loops, file-io

I have a long sequence of bits that I dumped from a file. Now, I want to take this sequence of bits and be able to extract every 8th bit from it. For example:

```
100010010101000001001110010001110000110100001010
000110100000101000000000000000000000000000001101
010010010100100001000100010100100000000000000000
etc
```

would give:

```
100110
(extraction from second line)
(extraction from third line)
etc
```

I have the following code so far:

```
 #/usr/bin/python

 with open("thebits.txt", 'r') as f:
        content = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]
        {//logic to extract every 8th bit from each line and print it}
```

How can I extract every 8th bit from each line?
.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simple slicing:

```
with open('thebits.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()[7::8]
```

Your example file gives:

```
100110
000001
100000
```

The slice `[7::8]` gives you every 8th character starting from the 8th (7 indexed from 0).

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(infile) as f:
    print("".join(line[7::8] for line in f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want each line separately:

```
with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        print(line[7::8])
```